# DocuSign automation process

Tags: docusignapi

Can we automate the complete process of DocuSign with a single click. Now we need to automate the process where we click a button and an email goes to the end customer for signing the document.

Can this be automated through the api's or through a trigger/class created in the Salesforce.

Another alternative which we need is to have the DocuSign link to be available in a portal where the customer can click and will be redirected DocuSign portal for e-signing.

Answer (score 0):

> we need to automate the process where we click a button and an email
>   goes to the end customer for signing the document

You can use the DocuSign [CreateEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) Api for this purpose. 
You can use this [Quickstart](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/usage/quickstart.html) guide to start building your applications using the DocuSign API.

Also take a look at the API recipe to [Request signature via e-mail](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/request-a-signature-via-email).

> Can this be automated through the api's or through a trigger/class
>   created in the Salesforce.

Take a look at DocuSign for [Salesforce integration](https://www.docusign.com/partner/docusign-salesforce).

https://www.docusign.com/solutions/salesforce